# Vuforia display video that was downloaded from the internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I need to develop an app, that uses `Vuforia cloud recognition` of object, and then display a video on top of that object. This `video file` needs to be downloaded from the internet from separate `web service`, using `recognized object identifier`. I was looking at `Vuforia samples`, and was able to configure `Cloud Recognition` to use correct `target manager database` - objects are recognized correctly. But I don't know how to do, so that after discovering this object, I would display an loader view, and when video is ready to play, then display this video. I don't know where and what to update in the code. I only found that some local `dataset` can be used, but I can't use local `dataset`, because videos I want to display, are supposed to be downloaded from the internet after detection. Can someone direct me, where in `Vuforia examples` I can update what is shown on the target?

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia cloud is only for markers.

As per your requirements
1. You need to use iOS code to download the video.
2. After that you have to show that video using AVPlayer.

Comment: I know I need to download that video myself, but the problem is, I don't know how to assign this video to that marker after it's downloaded. How to display it on that marker.

Comment: You have target IDs for each target. So you just have to store them with specific video.

Comment: I can't, this is in project requirements - after getting results from cloud, I need to use target ID to download video, and display it. I can't store a dataset in application, but need to download video and assign it to target in runtime. This is to avoid updating application after adding new objects to the cloud.

Comment: Then keep only one target. So every time you just have to download the video and assign that to single object it will be easier for you.